# Looking for web conference similar to zoom or appear.in but with ad hoc pricing

Tags: video-conferencing

We hold a group conference call three or four times a year, and would rather use a service which lets me pay for each meeting rather than monthly subscription that I am barely going to use.

The ideal service would include:

- Allow up to around 10 participants.
- Dial-in lines available, ideally local calls for US, UK, Ireland and Australia.
- Audio a must, video a nice to have.
- Screen sharing a nice to have.

Comment: just a comment because i'm not sure if it hits all your requirements, but why not for free: https://meet.jit.si/

Comment: meet.jit.si would be perfect, except when I tested the dial-in line the latency was pretty bad. Would say something in the phone and hear it come out the computer speaker a second later, or vice versa.

Comment: hmm, too bad. - fortunately i never had to use dial-in... maybe try a usual SIP-service.